# Where is the correct place to put event handlers in class components that have constructors?

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing a solution to a recent question I asked on here. However in order to make the logic work I must use a function. When I place the function below the constructor I get an error as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**If I can't place it in the constructor, or the render method where is the correct place to put handler functions?**

Comment: You have to use it without the `function` keyword, as it is inside a `class`.

Comment: If I do this, then in my onClick method can't read the function, says it's undefined. I'll post what I'm talking about above

Comment: That is a different issue, and related to binding of the `this` keyword to your function.

Comment: ok I'm looking into it

Comment: See the answer below, it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider This:

```
loginGetHandler() {
  //...
}
```

If you use this declaration for your function, don't forget to bind it in the constructor as:

```
constructor(){
//....
  this.loginGetHandler = this.loginGetHandler.bind(this);

}
```

---

Or as ES6 Named Arrow Function:

```
loginGetHandler = () => {
  //...
}
```

You will be needing no binding here as ES6 already does that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I appreciate it. So what exactly does binding do to the this keyword in this situation?

Comment: It's all about how JavaScript handling the `this` bind to the function scope, it's a topic you can [read about](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md), it's worth the time invested to understand.